# clipPath in multiple SVG tags

Tags: svg, cross-browser

Suppose you have multiple SVG tags where in each you define a different clip path with the same ID.

```
<svg id="svg1" width="200" height="200">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="nodeclipper">
            <rect width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>

<svg id="svg2" width="200" height="200">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="nodeclipper">
            <circle cx="20" cy="0" r="40" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

I also made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XwM6a/3/). What is the expected behaviour? I thought that an element could only reference definitions inside its own SVG tag, but that doesn't seem to be the case:

- Chrome 26: Uses `circle` clip path two times.
- Firefox 17: Uses `rect` clip path two times.
- Safari 6: Renders one `rect` and one `circle` clip path as expected.

It gets weird when you [hide one of the SVG tags](http://jsfiddle.net/XwM6a/4/) because Chrome and Safari then drop the `clip-path` entirely.

I know it works when the `clipPath`s have different IDs but is it supposed to be that way? As far as I see the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath) doesn't contain information about the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are doing is invalid per http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#IDAttribute this references http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/ which addresses this specific issue directly...

*Values of type ID MUST match the Name production. A name MUST NOT appear more than once in an XML document as a value of this type; i.e., ID values MUST uniquely identify the elements which bear them.*

Comment: Upvoted for the reference to the spec. While it's technically correct, it's also pretty mental behaviour in the context of how SVG documents are embedded in the page. SVGs are often pulled in from a variety of sources and for it to fall to the user to have to parse and re-pseudo-namespace everything to avoid potential clashes is pretty unfriendly.

Comment: Also, given that there are two separate svg docs (xml) inside an html doc (non-xml) - does that fall under the same spec?

Comment: There's only one document.

Comment: @AidanKane I couldn't agree more! I almost went insane trying to debug why clip-paths had been displaying improperly. Thanks for having SO!!!